# Does here miss "have": "What you been doing in there?"

Tags: grammaticality

In the book The Adventures of Tom Sawyer by Mark Twain on the first page there is a sentence:
"What you been doing in there?"
Isn't it correct "What have you been doing in there?"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, "What have you been doing..." is correct standard English.

Tom Sawyer is set in a poor community in Missouri, USA, and Tom is an uneducated lad. The people there speak in the dialect and idiom of the South, not in standard English.

"What you been doing..." is typical of the dialect of that part of the USA. It is not uncommon in casual speech in other dialects.

Comment: Is Missouri in the South?  This is definitely a non-standard dialect, but is it Southern?

Comment: Missouri was a Union state during the Civil War, but also a slave state. The state is half in the South and half in the Midwest, according to some people, and the dividing line is the Missouri river. Anywhere south of that river has more of a natural affinity with Kentucky, Tennessee, and Arkansas and is thus more southern.  Missouri north of the river has more in common with Illinois, Iowa, Nebraska, and Kansas.

Comment: Also common in casual speech in other dialects, I'd say.

Comment: If you call the state "Missoura" you're a Southerner. I didn't say "cracker", did I?